# Impact of reducing the number of distinct elements in the Count distinct problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, algorithms

I am dealing with the Count distinct problem and [Space saving algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205090/spacesaving-frequent-item-counter-in-python). The problem goes like that:
I have a stream of $N$ elements. The number of distinct elements is $D$. Space saving algorithm is an algorithm to count the top-$k$ elements by most occurrences. The algorithm uses only $m$ counters.
My question is, if I reduce the number of distinct elements from $D$ to $D-1$ (hence the number of elements in the stream decreases too) and the number of counters remains the same, what will be the impact on the accuracy of the algorithm? (I measure the accuracy by how well the $m$ counters predicted the actual frequency of the elements.)
I know that it'll improve the accuracy but I can't prove it.
If anyone has any advice, I'll be glad to hear.

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you're asking.  Are you speaking of a particular algorithm (which one?) or of *any* algorithm?  If *any* algorithm, then this is surely false; one can come up with an algorithm that intentionally wastes time if $D$ is not a power of $2$, for example.

Comment: Hey, yes, I’m speaking of a particular algorithm - Space saving algorithm. (I edited the question, thanks)

Comment: Some of us have never heard of "the Space saving algorithm." Maybe you could provide a link.

Comment: Added the link to the algorithm